# I can't find Lucia or Sophie

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to find Lucia and Sophie but they are both gone i haven't adopted them yet so i don't know what to do to find them. I've already looked everywhere in whitrunrun and windhelm but they are nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [UESPWiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lucia) Lucia's schedule is the following:

> Lucia wakes up at 8am and heads to the area outside the Temple of Kynareth, where she wanders around, begging all day. At 8pm, she goes to the Bannered Mare, where she stays inside for four hours. Then at midnight, she goes out behind the inn and sleeps on the ground. She gets up again at 8am the next morning and repeats the same schedule

But there is a bug when she completely disappears from the game:

> - Lucia may completely disappear from the game.

As for Sofie the [UESPWiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sofie) states:

> Starting her day at 8am, she sells her flowers for nine hours until 5pm. After that, she finally rests and can usually be found sitting near the New Gnisis Cornerclub. After three hours, she heads back to the barrel at the back of Niranye's house and sleeps until 8am. She will then repeat her schedule the following day.

I usually met her next to the exit to Docks in Windhelm.

If nothing else works, and you are on PC I would advise you to use cheats to teleport next to them. Look up the [moveto command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#moveto) to see how to do that.

Also both of these NPC were added with the Hearthfire add-on so make sure the data file is loaded.